# SharePoint site pages vs application pages

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm learning the difference between these to concepts.
I want to build a public Sharepoint site, and is one better than the other for this use, or is it too general of a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a very general level; application pages are stored on the web server's file system (also known as the "12 hive") and run in a more priviledged security context.  You tend to use these to create administrative interfaces.

Site pages (such as default.aspx) are user-targeted, and available for customization via SharePoint designer.

Comment: so if i am making an internet site, i would customize site pages?

Comment: Any user facing page will tend to be a site page (if you set up your site collection as a Publishing Portal, you can very easily generate new site pages through the UI.)  But like I said, i'm speaking in generalities.

Answer (score 1):

Site Pages can contain one or more webpart zones each zone may contain one or more webpart zones.
Site pages can customized
Site Pages not supprot code behind file.

Application pages such as Create.aspx,Themeweb.aspx.
Application pages Can't customized
Application pages support code behind file.

Answer (score -1):

**Site Pages:-**
Site Pages are Site or Web Scoped,
User can customize Site Pages,
Site Pages are stored in Content Database,
You cannot have custom code in Site Pages,
Site Pages are Un-ghosted Pages.

**Application Page:-**
Application Pages are farm scoped,
No customization can be done by the user,
Application Pages are stored in WFE(Web Front End) in _layouts folder,
You can have custom code in your Application Pages,
Application Pages are Ghosted Pages.

Comment: We can do customization in the Application pages.